# What etext sources do we have for the Gothic Language?

Tags: grammar, resource-request, history, datasets

It is very hard to search for "Gothic" in Google, because it finds modern gothic stuff which is not what I'm looking for. I found the word "" (but I can't find a definition haha), and searching for that reveals a [Gothic Wikipedia](https://got.wikipedia.org/wiki/%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8C%BB%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8D%82%F0%90%8C%B4%F0%90%8C%B9%F0%90%8C%BA%F0%90%8D%83)! But I can't Google-translate-stumble-my-way-around the site, because Google doesn't translate Gothic. So it takes orders of magnitude longer to figure out each word and try and debug what I am looking at.

The only other thing I can find is the [Gothic Lord's Prayer](https://wikisource.org/wiki/%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8D%84%F0%90%8D%84%F0%90%8C%B0_%F0%90%8C%BF%F0%90%8C%BD%F0%90%8D%83%F0%90%8C%B0%F0%90%8D%82), also on the wiki.

I would like to find something original to the Gothic people. I know we don't have much from their culture, but do we have *anything*? Like even a short poem? Maybe a story? Maybe a carving?

The reason for asking is because I am looking for primary sources to learn how to speak Gothic and learn the Gothic grammar. I got the grammar book but don't know yet about if there exists resources on the web available for original texts. Last time I asked a similar question on History stackexchange and they said it would be better on Linguistics, because you guys know more about the language side of history.

Comment:  is "Alareiks", which as far as I can tell isn't actually attested in written Gothic—but Latin sources record the name of a Visigothic king as "Alaricus", so the Gothic form can be back-derived from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main corpus for Gothic is Wulfila's sixth-century translation of the Bible, which is attested across a number of different codices (the silver-lettered Codex Argenteus being the most famous one). All the surviving parts have been [digitized and put online](http://www.wulfila.be/gothic/browse/) by the Wulfila project.

That said, though, it'll be much easier to learn with a good grammar and/or textbook than just by looking at the Bible. I've heard good things about Lambdin's *Introduction to the Gothic Language*, though I haven't read it myself.

Comment: So there's no poem's then in Gothic?

Comment: @LancePollard Not as far as I'm aware. There are a few other works in Gothic from a few centuries after Wulfila, but they're shorter and mostly fragmentary. I don't think there's any attested poetry.